# Current page indicator MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

In my WPF application I'm trying to navigate to other 'pages' using the ContentControl.
I have this working so far, in my MainViewModel I have initiated the other viewmodels that should be a part of the MainViewModel.

I display my views with a datatemplate like this:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NewsViewModel}">
            <Views:NewsView />
        </DataTemplate>
```

I got a ItemsControl with TextBlocks to display the View(models) PageName property, when I click on this, it does set the 'CurrentView' property to the according ViewModel and it gets displayed. So this aint the problem... However, the issue I come across now is how to let the textblock display the CurrentView I have, for example I want it to be another color then the rest of the textblocks so the user can see which view(model) is active.

I tried to do this in the Style for the textblock with a DataTrigger but this only accepts constant values, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not switch the `ItemsControl` to a `ListBox` since it has built-in selection features? You can style it so it hides the selection highlight and looks the same as your `ItemsControl`, and base your trigger off of `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`.

If you don't want to do that, you can probably use a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to pass the current ViewModel and the active ViewModel to a converter, which would return True if the items are the same, or false if not.

Comment: The first suggestion seems like the best one! Thanks!

Not to be lazy or something, but how can you align the Items in a listbox horizontally?

Comment: @MrZunz You can overwrite the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` template to use a Horizontal `StackPanel`, or a `WrapPanel` (default is a Vertical `StackPanel`)

Comment: Alright, I got that now. Still having problems setting the foreground of the selected item though. There is enough to find on google, but they're all freaking crappy...

Comment: @MrZunz Usually for setting the SelectedItem Background/Foreground, you need to overwrite the SystemColors for the ListBox. There's an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298301/302677

Answer (score 0):

Create a `IValueConverter` that returns if the supplied view is the active view and add it to the binding of the DataTrigger.

Sample Converter:

```
public class IsViewActiveConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == [activeView];
    }
}
```

Sample xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <local:IsViewActiveConverter x:Key="IsViewActive"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding View, Converter={StaticResource IsViewActive}}" Value="True">
```