# Disabling Listbox is not changing background color in style

Tags: wpf, background, listbox, styles, disabled-control

I have this simple style that does not change the `ListBox` `Background` when the `ListBox` is disabled:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" >                    
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Snoop does not help me on this one and I cannot figure a simple way without overriding templates.  Anyone have a simple way to get this working?  TIA.

Comment: Did you set the background on the ListBox itself as well?

Comment: @H.B - Then he would be overriding his Style

Comment: ListBox colors strange.   This post may lead you to and answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298282/wpf-listbox-selected-item-background

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI: That was exactly my point.

Comment: @H.B. - I still don't understand your comment. The trigger WORKS EXCEPT the IsEnabled = False so why would he override his style. He needs to make a template

Comment: @BalamBalam, I am not styling selected item but listbox itself.

Comment: @e28Makaveli, can yo please share the working sample code in which you override the template of ListBox. Because its not working for me after I override the ListBox template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by overriding the template

Comment: Looks like the only way to go.

Comment: can yo please share the working sample code in which you override the template of ListBox. Because its not working for me after I override the ListBox template

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of the listbox itself when the listbox is disabled by simply changing the colors that the built-in template is using.  You can do this via style resources.  Just paste the below code into your Listbox element and the background will be transparent when you disable the box.

```
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

It is also very common to want to modify the background color of a single item when it's highlighted and when the box loses focus.. to change these, you can reference this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298301/1721136