# Change background of disabled listView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to set the style of a disabled ListView. But no matter what I do, the listView stays at the default style when disabled.

**What I've already tried**:

1. Setting the System Color `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` to `Transparent` according to this thread: [Change disabled listbox background to gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773669/change-disabled-listbox-background-to-gray)
2. I also looked at the style of the listView at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788747%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and redefined the `DisabledBorderLightColor`
3. And of course I created a Trigger

All these tries can be seen in the resource-section of the window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FF00FF00</Color>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Unselect" Click="UnselectItem"></Button>
    <ListView x:Name="_listView" 
              Grid.Row="1"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ObjectToShow}" 
              IsEnabled="True"
              SelectionChanged="SelectItem">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property1}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property2}"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This is the according c#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var objectsToShow = new List<ObjectToShow>
        {
            new ObjectToShow
            {
                Property1 = "Content1Property1",
                Property2 = "Content1Property2"
            },
            new ObjectToShow
            {
                Property1 = "Content2Property1",
                Property2 = "Content2Property2"
            },
        };

        _listView.ItemsSource = objectsToShow;
    }

    private void SelectItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _listView.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void UnselectItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _listView.SelectedItem = null;
        _listView.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

public class ObjectToShow
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

I just want the listView to have the Red background when it is disabled. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ListView` Style to something like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <!-- Here comes your custom disabled background color -->
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd"
                                    Value="Red"/>
                            <!-- Here comes your custom disabled background color -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

It's pretty annoying when you have to overwrite the whole Template of a Control, just to change a tiny bit of it... But sometimes you're left little choice.

In this case, since the Trigger that changes the Background color is in the ControlTemplate, there's no way to override it with a Style Trigger.

Comment: could you please provide the `xmlns=`-statement for `Microsoft_Windows_Themes`. Do I realy have to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`?

Comment: That, or you could replace the chrome with a regular Border, and add triggers for MouseOver behavior and all that yourself. Keep in mind that WPF controls are lookless, and the ListView doesn't explicitly support a custom disabled background. It's just a matter of how the control is templated by your default theme, and you want to override that... So you have to, at all effects, create a new Template. I've just used the default W7 Aero template as a base, but it is completely up to you.

Comment: Or... You could try overriding the system Brush it uses... But once again, which Brush the control uses depends entirely on the theme. Overriding Brushes is a hack, after all. That's why I'm suggesting this, because it's the only "correct" way to do it in WPF.

Comment: You are probably right. But I still struggle with the fact that the `ListView` should be lookless. I mean, it has Properties like `Background`. These are for a nice look!

Comment: I can relate, believe me :P Let's just say that Controls don't define their own look, but they *suggest* how they should look with a handful of properties... Then it's up to the "templater" to use them or not, and how

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define your own control template overriding the default ListView template for this one.

Or you can try if the built-in control brush does what you need:

```
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Crimson"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListView.Style>
```

Comment: I have already tried that (first point in my list of things that I did) to no avail.