# WPF Changing ListboxItem background Color when Selected

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I have a surfacelistbox as follows

```
<s:SurfaceListBox x:Name="viewList" Height="200" Width="Auto" SelectedIndex="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource views}, XPath=Views/View}"
                DisplayMemberPath="@Title"                    
                SelectionChanged="viewList_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </s:SurfaceListBox>
```

I've styled the items from the App.xaml file as follows

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBoxItem}">

        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" 
                     Color="#0071bc"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="480"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,20,0,20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="57"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="TitilliumText22L"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#3c3c3c" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="#383838" Offset="0.6"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="#6d6e6e" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0071bc"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0071bc"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

My Problem is, the backgroundcolor of the selected item remains white as opposed to the colors described in the styling. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Come on just search SO listbox background  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298282/listbox-selected-item-background

Comment: Try the answer to this question: [WPF: Change background color for selected ListBox item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/wpf-change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item).

Comment: Blam, I already searched and none of the solutions worked for me unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found your answer yet, but I just ran into the same problem. Try setting the surface color resource in your style. You can find the list of surface colors here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.surfacecolors_properties.aspx

Make sure you import the namespace for SurfaceColors

```
xmlns:sc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Surface.Presentation;assembly=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation"
```

Then update the surface color in your SurfaceListBox style:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox>
     <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="s:SurfaceListBoxItem">
              <Style.Resources>
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static sc:SurfaceColors.ListBoxItemSelectionBackgroundBrushKey }" Color="#FFA2CD65"/>
              </Style.Resources>
          </Style>
     </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</s:SurfaceListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create your own ListBox. USUALLY there is not a need to do this, but if you feel you must, make sure that you override the GetContainerForItemOverride method

```
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new SurfaceListBoxItem();
    }
```

Comment: No, he's using SurfaceListBox from the Microsoft Surface SDK