# How can I change selected item's background color in Windows Phone?

Tags: background, listbox, windows-phone, selected

How can I change selected item's background color that in listbox which has datatemplate in Windows Phone?

I have seen that it can be with Setter Properties. Where I will write them?

Thanks.

**Code**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listLocs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="605" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" SelectionChanged="listLocs_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,155,0,0" BorderBrush="#FF030042" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="#FF030042">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="/Images/Pin2.png" Width="60"  Height="60" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF030042"  FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF030042" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: you can check this question :

[Change color of ListBoxItem background when selected and unfocused][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298282/listbox-selected-item-background]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298282/listbox-selected-item-background

Comment: Thank you but I did not understand it because of its extras :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in code behind altough in selectchanged event handler:

```
    private void listLocs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem myitem = listLocs.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
       SolidColorBrush brush =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));
       myitem.Background = brush;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. myitem is taking null value.

Comment: this mean that is no item is selected are you sure that you selected an item? you can although check in debugging mode the type which return.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I am taking its Name from my datatemplate class and showing it in a label.

Comment: what is the type of selected item ? or it is null although?

Comment: I am keeping it in my class

private void listLocs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedItem = listLocs.SelectedItem as Items;
            lblLoc.Text = selectedItem.Name;
            
        }


My class,

public class Items
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string Description
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }