# How to customize the view of selected item in ListBox? (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to customize the view of item that was selected in ListBox control? In my case I want to define the color of background of selected item.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   private void listLocs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem myitem = listLocs.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
   SolidColorBrush brush =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));
   myitem.Background = brush;
}
```

More details from:
[How can I change selected item's background color in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184237/how-can-i-change-selected-items-background-color-in-windows-phone)

Comment: Does it restore the previous view of item when I select the another item?

Comment: This should do that, but in case not you can make loop before the previous code to reset the color back to default...

Comment: seems it doesn't work. It throws NullReferenceException. Maybe It's important to say, that I use a custom ItemTemplate for ListBox, which include just a TextBlock in a StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by styling the ListBoxItem with the ItemContainerStyle property of the ListBox. Use the following steps

1. In Visual Studio (or Blend) open the page (xaml) with your ListBox on it.
2. View the design.
3. Right click the ListBox and select Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)
4. Select a name a location for this style
5. In the selection states add a new animation for background.

So, your Storyboard would change from:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

To:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Should I create new empty or edit existing ItemContainer style?