# ListBox and ListView Highlighting .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

With .NET 4.0 it appears highlighting of ListBox and ListView has changed

Below is code I have used for years in several places on .NET 3.5 and highlight when not focused has stopped working on 4.0 and 4.5

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Pink"/>
            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[ListBox SelectedItem Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298282/listbox-selected-item-background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .NET 4.0 there are some new SytemColors
This appears to be the .NET 4.0 way
According to comment this changed in 4.5 - not 4.0.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Foregroud of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <!-- Foregroud of selected item when not focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Pink"/>
            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

At first I though the definition of ControlBrushKey had changed but it has not
It appears the behavior of ControlBrushKey has changed in this situation

*Note the behavior changes with GridView*

Comment: Please note that `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` is only for .NET 4.5 or later. It is not in .NET 4.0