# Avoid Background change of selected item in a ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView of items and I change the background of the items based on binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding someCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="someValue">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="someOtherValue">
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <!-- and many more -->

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

As you can see I also change the border of the selected item.

The problem is that when an item is selected it's background changes, overriding my DataTriggers.

Is there a way to avoid the background change?

Comment: Because of how you're doing it. What about just separating out your objects? Have your background changed Border separate from another Border you're using for Selected state with the one you're applying the BorderBrush to higher in the z-index with a transparent bg so you can keep your changed background while showing your selected border over it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559833/listbox-and-listview-highlighting-net-4-0

Comment: @ChrisW. The problem I had with that is that then I have to have the `IsSelected` trigger set properties of an element that is in the `ItemTemplate`, that does not work, so I would have to use a relative source binding from the boarder back to the `ListViewItem`, and that is a mess... but I'll probably end up doing that anyways, thanks :)

Comment: @Frisbee Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem as I dont want to change the selection color, but avoid it overriding the color I set for the non selected item

Comment: Have you defined a `DataTemplate` as well? or do you just try to set the default template?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have set templates for the `ItemTemplate` if that is what you mean.

Comment: ha ha yes! sorry should have been more specific in my question. I have similar set up in my app, the way I am setting the background is by using `<Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>` but my style opening tag looks like this `<Style>`. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid background color of ListViewItem by changing the ItemContainerStyle of ListViewItem.

```
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent"  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                                    </Trigger>                            
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```