# Background color in C# WPF comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On Windows, it is possible to change the various colours used by the UI elements (sorry, I only have windows in French at work):

[image: Windows colours dialog]

By using global styles in our C# WPF application, I made sure the various UI elements always use the same colours no matter which colour I select in the dialog above.

For example, we have the following global styles for the comboboxes:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultForegroundBrush}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ControlDefaultForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxFocusVisualStyle}" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectionBackgroundColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

So I played around modifying all the colours:

[image: Modified colours]

And we always get the same colours for the combo boxes:

[image: OK comboboxes]

Then I decided to test by selecting the following theme:

[image: Selection a Windows theme]

I now have the following problem:

[image: Bad comboboxes]

For a combo box, what is the name of the background system colour when an item is selected but not being selected? In this example the background colour is black instead of being grey (with a 3D effect).

It is possible to get rid of this background colour by using a global style?
Note that our global styles are still working when the combo box items are displayed. The items background/foreground colours and the highlight colours are still OK:

[image: Styles still working for items]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559833/listbox-and-listview-highlighting-net-4-0

Comment: Thanks @Paparazzi. When an item is selected in a combobox (not when the item is being selected), do you know if it is possible to keep the "3D effect"? I'm referring to the same style as the combobox with the "Bureau" label in the first image and the combobox with "Objets 3D" label in the second image.